# Create WebPages like IMDB

Tags: content-management-system

1. I will be building a site for music reviews. Say, i review a album of "Summer Hits 2011". It would contain about 10-15 artists. Now, i have portfolios of all these 10-15 artists. In the review, the artist names should be a hyperlink. Is there any way to automatically make the artist names as hyperlinks, instead of manually making it a hyperlink by linking to the artist's page. I know the question is little bit vague, but i tried my best in putting it the right way.
2. I though of using asp.net. What do you guys suggest ? I have heard of CMS solutions like Drupal. If you can point me in the right direction it would be great.
3. A silly question - Where and how the information is stored. Pick a movie page in IMDB. Do they create a html page for this movie and keep it on the server. Or do they just query from DB and present it in template ?

Thanks,
Dev.

Comment: Yes of course. Parse the text, recognise artists' names and lookup their URL's, replace them by an HTML anchor. How you actually **do** it depends on lots of things you haven't told us.

Comment: If i'm writing an aspx page, i would simply design, put the content and publish it. When do i actually do this parsing and replacing ?

Comment: I don't know anything about aspx, and I don't know what special meanings "design", "put" and "publish" may have. But you've got the text (content), and you can process it any way you like before you send it to the browser (which is presumably one of "put" and "publish", but I don't know which). Or you could even send it to the browser and then have a Javascript program that crawls over it and replaces certain text by links; but I wouldn't advise that unless you have no choice.

Comment: And in answer to your third question (I don't remember seeing that there when I first commented on your question): I would be very surprised if they cached HTML pages - it will be generated on the fly from the database. That is what CGI scripts are for.